# Which of the following functions are in $L^p(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I have the following problem:

> Let $u,u_i:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by:
>   $$u(x):=\begin{cases}|x|^{-\alpha},\quad \text{with}\nobreakspace x\neq 0, \ \\ 0,\qquad \text{with} \nobreakspace x=0,\end{cases}$$ and 
>   $$u_i(x):=\begin{cases}\partial_i|x|^{-\alpha},\quad \text{with}\nobreakspace x\neq 0,\\0, \qquad\text{with}\nobreakspace x=0, \end{cases}$$
>   with $i=1,...,n$.
>   Now for each case
>
> $1) \Omega=B_1(0)\backslash\{0\}$,
>
> $2) \Omega= \mathbb{R}^n\backslash\overline{B_1(0)}$,
>
> $3) \Omega=\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$
>
> determine for which $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\ u(x), u_i(x)$ are in $L^p(\Omega)$.

For the case $u(x)$:

In $1)$: For $u(x)$ to be in $L^p(\Omega)$ $p-\alpha$ must be greater than $-1$

In $2)$: For $u(x)$ to be in $L^p(\Omega)$ $p-\alpha$ must be less than $-1$

In $3)$: For $u(x)$ to be in $L^p(\Omega)$ there shouldn't be such an $\alpha$

For the case $u_i(x)$:

In $1)$: For $u_i(x)$ to be in $L^p(\Omega)$ $p-\alpha$ must be less than $1$

In $2)$: For $u_i(x)$ to be in $L^p(\Omega)$ $p-\alpha$ must be greater than $1$

In $3)$: For $u_i(x)$ to be in $L^p(\Omega)$ there shouldn't be such an $\alpha$

I got these results by only looking at $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Are these statements true?
How can I show this for $\mathbb{R}^n$? Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: In the multivariate case, working with spherical coordinates will allow you to reduce to the 1-dimensional case.

Comment: This exact question was asked earlier today: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2620884/power-function-in-lp#comment5412898_2620884